# R dplyr get sorted row number

Tags: r, dplyr

dplyr is returning the original row number and not the current row number:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("A", "B"), b=c(1,2))
----------------
a   b
A   1
B   2
-----------------
df %>% arrange(desc(b)) %>% mutate(row_number(a))
-----------------
a   b   row_number(a)
B   2   2
A   1   1
```

how do I get a column that returns 1,2?

Comment: `row_number()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df %>% arrange(desc(b)) %>% mutate(row_number())

  # a b row_number()
# 1 B 2            1
# 2 A 1            2
```

Comment: We've all been there...don't look through my history